# who is working hard when executing pg_dump with -h remote_ip option

Tags: postgresql

I have one machine with postgres client libraries (machine_C) and one machine with postgres server (machine_S)

When I run pg_dump from the machine with postgres client  and use the -h option with the server IP.  Who is actually doing the hard work.  Is it the server machine (machine_S) or the client machine (machine_C).

In addition, is it better to run this command locally on the server machine and copy the file or to use the -h option and to write it directly on the client machine

Thanks

Comment: Define "working hard". The server is going to "work hard" because it has to retrieve every row of every table in the database you are dumping. The client is also going to work hard because it has to _write_ every row of every table in the database. And the network cards are going to work hard because they have to send (or receive) every row of every table in the database (plus the protocol overhead)

Comment: Ok I will ask it a little differently.  My goal is to dump the data from the server to a file and eventually copy it to the client disk.  Will the client work less hard if I execute the command directly on the server and then copy the file to the client disk compared to having the command run from the client with -h option.

Comment: typically I am sipping on coffee while it is executing. no "working hard" here.

Answer (score 0):

In the light of your comment above, the correct answer is to run it on the client machine:

- The work that the database has to do is the same.
- The amount of data transferred is roughly the same.
- You save the time and I/O capacity of first writing and then reading the dump file on the server machine.

There is a small trade-off if you are using `pg_dump -Fc` with compression – dumping on the server will hog the server machine's CPU, but the amount of data transferred over the network will be less. Consider doing that if your network is particularly lame, otherwise just run it on the client machine.